# Gmail video chat tester bot?

Tags: gmail, chat, bot

For instance in Skype I have such as service in my contacts list called **"Echo / Sound Test Service"** which you can call up, record a message, and it plays the message back.

Does anyone know if there is a bot that can be called when you want to test out your Google video chat via Gmail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gmail checks settings with built-in tools. You simply go to [Chat settings page](http://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/chat) and click on `Verify your settings` (it has a plus sign to the left). There the instructions are straightforward: camera capture is shown to the right and mic level indicates if it's connected.

If you are using Google Hangouts instead of chat, you need to [create an empty hangout](https://hangouts.google.com/start), cancel the invitation dialog, and then click on the cogwheel at the top of the page (move your mouse if you don't see it).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Any idea how this is today?

Comment: With Hangouts enabled, it's trickier, but doable. Switch to phone dialing, call your own number, but don't wait for the rings and hang up. The window will stay open, so just move the mouse to reveal the tools panel on top and click on the cog wheel. Done.

Comment: It tells me I have to buy some credit to do that :(

Comment: @beruic: Ah, sorry about that. I didn't realize you were outside the USA. See my edited answer with the updated link.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to https://meet.google.com, start meeting and join this meeting via mobile phone

Adjust volume or mute the phone to avoid audio feedback