# Does Google+ have any video chat bots you can call to test out the video hangout functionality?

Tags: gmail, chat, bot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gmail Video Chat Tester Bot?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24142/gmail-video-chat-tester-bot)

For instance in Skype I have such as service in my contacts list called "Echo / Sound Test Service" which you can call up, record a message, and it will play the message back.

I'm looking for a similar service using something like this for Google+ Hangouts.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice? It's the same system.

Comment: @dnbrv Cause I wasn't completely certain it was the same system...I mean I know they both go through Google but that doesn't guarantee they are the same system.